# Mysql Trigger: Result consisted of more than one row

Tags: mysql, triggers, row

I have 3 tables:

Module:

```
id_module   | name
--------------------
1             users
2             roles
...
```

Profile:

```
id_profile   | name
--------------------
1             admin
2             promoter
```

And Permission

```
id   | id_profile  | id_module | read | write | modify | delete
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

What I want is a trigger is to fill the table permission every time I insert a new module ... but for every existing profile.

Thus:

```
INSERT INTO `module` (`name`) VALUES
    ('user'),
    ('roles');
```

Existing profiles **admin** and **promoter** permission table would be filled this way:

```
id   | id_profile  | id_module | read | write | modify | delete
---------------------------------------------------------------
1      1             1           0      0       0        0
2      1             2           0      0       0        0
3      2             1           0      0       0        0
4      2             2           0      0       0        0
```

For this, I created the following trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `create_permission` AFTER INSERT ON `module`
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
    DECLARE `my_profile` INT(11) ;

    SELECT id_profile INTO `my_profile` FROM profile WHERE state <>3;

    INSERT INTO `permission` (`id_profile`, `id_module`, `read`, `write`, `modify`, `delete`) VALUES(`my_profile`, NEW.`id_module `,0,0,0,0);

END;
```

It works well when there is a profile ... when more than one when I return "*Result consisted of more than one row*"

I read that this problem arises when you declare a variable that supports a single value... You can insert records for each id of the table profile?

Answer (score 1):

As you found out, you may only assign scalar values to a variable.

To iterate over the many results of a `SELECT` query, you need to use a [`CURSOR`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/cursors.html).

I personnaly dislike the cumbersome `CURSOR` syntax. In your particular case, I would advise the much simpler [`INSERT INTO...SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html) trick:

```
INSERT INTO permission (id_profile, id_module, read, write, modify, delete)
SELECT id_profile, NEW.id_module,0,0,0,0 FROM profile WHERE state <> 3;
```

Comment: Hi, this is very interesting and simple your solution. But it is possible to make an if statement before inserting?

I just want to know if id_profile is '1 'to be inserted on the permissions 1,1,1,1 ... and if the id_profile is another number, insert 0,0,0,0.

Is that possible in a single sentence or it can be solved with a cursor?